# How To Find BASH Shell Array Length (number of elements)

Tags: shell-script, centos, xen

I have the following matrix:

```
LCANTIDAD_VM_=4
while [ $i -lt $LCANTIDAD_VM_  ];
do
    VM_NAME_=$(xe vm-list is-control-domain=false | head -n -$aux2 | tail -1 | cut -d ":" -f 2)
    VM_NAME_=$(trim $VM_NAME_)
    UUID=$(obtener_uuid $VM_NAME_)
    array_vm[$i,0]=$VM_NAME_
    LSPACE_DISK_=$(space_vm $UUID)
    array_vm[$i,1]=$LSPACE_DISK_
    array_vm[$i,2]="FALSE"
    array_vm[$i,3]="FALSE"
    array_vm[$i,4]="FALSE"
    let "i++"
    aux2=$(expr $aux2 + $aux3)
done
```

I need to know how many elements the matrix has.
In the following way I get the number of columns:

```
SIZE_=${#array_vm[@]}
```

In the variable **LCANTIDAD_VM_** I have the number of times that iterates and in that fragment of code I could have the quantity. But if I add a condition before adding an element I lose the amount and I need to know it.

Comment: You've created an array that you're calling a matrix; bash only knows the number of elements of the array. What are you doing in your conditional? If you only create 5 items per LCANTIDAD_VM_, then you'll have 5 * array-elements "matrix items"...

Comment: Could you post the output of `declare -p array_vm` ?

Comment: There are no `matrix` in shell, only one-dimensional lists (called arrays). The only way in which the code you present could work is if the array is declared as an `Associative` array. An associative array use strings as indexes, not integers. Therefore, the number from `"${#array_vm[@]}"` is the total count of assigned elements. The keys could be listed with `echo "${!array_vm[@]}"`.

Comment: `declare -p array_vm` not supported. 

I need to have a structure where I keep the information name, size, process. Accustomed to C I came up with a matrix. To then sort by size with some simple algorithm.
I had started to make this program with a list within a text file. But I think it's better to handle it with variables and not create temporary files.

Comment: Then you are **not** using bash. Bash has supported that option since bash 2.03 (from 1999-02-19 (~20 years ago)). I just wonder why your title claims that the issue is with bash ?.

Comment: Issac: I have created a simple script with the instruction you have requested and the answer is declare: `array_vm not: found.` I have executed with `sh`, `bash` and `./script`
`bash --version: GNU bash, version 3.2.25 (1) -release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: My name is Isaac, not Issac. And it is usual to use a @ before the name so a notification is sent to the user. I have not received any notification about your message, it was just luck that I had the tab open and re-read it. What I meant to ask is that you included the command I posted just after the loop (after the done would be fine) inside the script you posted, not a new script whitout the definition of `array_vm`. And, after edited (you may make a backup copy to be on the safe side) you execute it and report which (if any) errors were reported and command output (if any). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is provided by @Isaac There is no shell matrix, only one-dimensional lists (called arrays). So the method I was looking for does not exist. Finally in each sector I saved the data with delimiters and created auxiliary functions to obtain it.